# Equal probability of having even/odd number of ones in many Bernoulli trials with different probabilities?

Tags: pr.probability

This problem has probably been solved somewhere but I could not find it. We have $n$ Bernoulli random trials $X_i$ with different occurrence probabilities, $\mathrm{Pr}[X_i=1]=p_i>p_{\min}>0$ for $i=1,2,\dots,n$ and some constant $p_{\min}$ what is the probability of having even number of ones when $n$ is very large? I guess that this probability is equal to $\frac{1}{2}$ but how can I prove this? I know how to prove this for the case when all $p_i$'s are equal but how can we prove it for different $p_i$'s? (In case this helps to solve the problem we can assume that $0<p_i \le 0.5$.)

Comment: If the probabilities $p_i$ are very small, then in more than half the cases the total number will be even $0$. You have to at least make some assumptions on $p_i$.

Comment: Thanks for you point. I added a minimum constraint on $p_i$'s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability that an even number of trials succeed is exactly
$$ \frac12\biggl( 1 + \prod_{i=1}^n (1-2p_i)\Biggr).$$
This is a standard elementary application of probability generating functions.

Comment: I notice that Will Sawin also posted this solution, but deleted it.  Actually this question is too elementary for MO.